# Eliminar un elemento de ListView y DB SQLite con OnItemLongClickListener

Tags: android-studio, listview, base-de-datos

Estoy intentando eliminar elementos de un ListView manteniendo el click, lo cual funciona pero cuando salgo y entro de nuevo en la activity, **me vuelven a aparecer** los elementos que borré.

Creo que esto sucede porque no elimino el elemento también de la BaseDeDatos, ya que **no se cómo hacerlo**. Se me había ocurrido algo así pero en vez de borrarme sólo el elemento seleccionado, **me borra de la BD todos los elementos de la ListView**:

```
        listaFavoritos.setLongClickable(true);
    listaFavoritos.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            SQLiteDatabase db=conn.getWritableDatabase();
            db.rawQuery("DELETE FROM favoritos", null)
                listaInfo.remove(i);
                adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Mi clase BaseDeDatos:

```
public class BaseDeDatos extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public BaseDeDatos(Context context) {
    super(context, "libros.db", null, 2);
}
private static final String tabla_favoritos = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS favoritos(titulo text)";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS libros (Id text, Titulo text, Autor text, Sinopsis text, FechaDePublicacion text, Editorial text, CantidadDePaginas text, Idioma text, Categorias text)");
    db.execSQL("insert into libros values('1', 'El Resplandor', 'Stephen King', '¿Qué ha sido de Danny Torrance? Descúbrelo al final de este volumen, que incluye el inicio de Doctor Sueño, la continuación de El resplandor. REDRUM. Esa es la palabra que Danny había visto en el espejo. Y, aunque no sabía leer, entendió que era un mensaje de horror. Tenía cinco años, y a esa edad pocos niños son conscientes de que los espejos invierten las imágenes, y menos aún diferencian entre realidad y fantasía. Pero Danny tenía pruebas de que sus fantasías relacionadas con el resplandor del espejo acabarían cumpliéndose.', '28-01-1977', 'Doubleday', '447', 'Ingles', 'Terror'), ('2', 'Forbidden', 'Tabitha Suzuma', 'No podemos. Si empezamos, ¿cómo vamos a pararlo? Lochan y Maya siempre se han sentido más amigos que hermanos. Ante la incapacidad de cuidarlos de su madre alcohólica y la ausencia de un padre que los abandonó, los dos jóvenes deben hacerse cargo de sus tres hermanos menores y esconder su situación a los servicios sociales, porque ninguno de los dos es mayor de edad. La responsabilidad que comparten y las dificultades a las que se enfrentan les unen, hasta empujarlos a enamorarse. Ambos saben que su relación está mal y que no debe continuar, pero al mismo tiempo no pueden controlar sus emociones y la atracción que los domina.', '10-05-2010', 'OZ', '387', 'Español', 'Ficción'),('3', 'Cazadores de Sombras', 'Harald Zwart', 'En la ciudad de Nueva York, una adolescente aparentemente común llamada Clary Fray descubre que ella desciende de una línea de guerreros, mitad ángeles, quienes protegen a la humanidad de los demonios. Después de que su madre desaparece, Clary une fuerzas con un grupo de cazadores de sombras e ingresa al Inframundo, un sitio peligroso y alterno lleno de demonios, brujos, vampiros, hombres lobo y criaturas sobrenaturales.', '22-07-2013', 'Simon & Schuster', '948', 'Español', 'Ficción'),('4', 'Beautiful Disaster', 'Jamie McGuire', 'La chica buena Abby no bebe, no se mete en líos y trabaja muy duro. Cree que ha enterrado su oscuro pasado, pero cuando llega a la universidad, un rompecorazones conocido por sis ligues de una noche pone en peligro su sueño de una nueva vida. El chico malo Travis Maddox , sexy, musculoso y cubierto de tatuajes, es justamente el tipo de chico que le atrae a Abby, justamente lo que quiere evitar. Dedica sus noches a ganar dinero en un club de lucha itinerante y sus dias a ser el estudiante ejemplar y el seductor mas popular del campus. Toda una mezcla explosiva. Intrigado por el rechazo de Abby, Travis intenta colarse en su vida proponiendole una apuesta que trastocará sus mundos y lo cambiará todo.', '26-05-2011', 'Simon & Schuster', '567', 'Ingles', 'Romance'),('5', 'Hush Hush', 'Becca Fitzpatrick', 'Cuando Patch se convierte en su nuevo compañero de laboratorio de biología, Nora siente a la vez atracción y repulsión hacia este extraño personaje que parece tener acceso a sus pensamientos. Luego se entera de que Patch es un ángel caído que quiere convertirse en humano.', '13-10-2009', 'Ediciones B', '647', 'Ingles', 'Romance'),('6', 'Los juegos del hambre', 'Collins Suzanne', 'En lo que alguna vez fue Norteamérica, la Capital de Panem mantiene sus 12 distritos obligándolos a seleccionar a un niño y a una niña, llamados Tributos, a competir en un evento televisado nacionalmente llamados Juegos del Hambre. Cada ciudadano debe ver pelear a muerte a los jóvenes. El Trbuto del Distrito 12, Katniss Everdeen sólo confía en sus habilidades de caza y buenos instintos en una arena en donde debe sobrevivir contra la humanidad.', '14-09-2008', 'Rba-Molino', '847', 'Español', 'Fantasía'),('7', 'Misery', 'Stephen King', 'Un autor se recupera de un accidente y es cuidado por una admiradora que le insiste escribir un libro sólo para ella.', '08-06-1987', 'Viking Press', '320', 'Ingles', 'Terror'),('8', 'Oscuros', 'Kate Lauren', 'La historia de Daniel y Luce, dos almas predestinadas a encontrarse y condenadas a perderse... Helstone, Inglaterra, 1854. Es noche cerrada y dos jóvenes conversan en una remota casa de campo. Se sienten irresistiblemente atraídos el uno por el otro, pero él insiste en que no pueden estar juntos.', '08-12-2009', 'Penguin Random House', '416', 'Ingles', 'Drama'),('9', 'Eleanor & Park', 'Rowell Rainbow', 'Dos chicos de un colegio, que se conocen por una situación fortuita en el autobús escolar, haciendo que de poco a poco su amistad vaya evolucionando en algo más. Pero no todo en la vida es fácil, al final, los dos protagonistas tendrán que luchar por mantenerse juntos, he impedir que el padrastro de Eleanor los separen para siempre.', '07-10-2012', 'Aguilar', '333', 'Ingles', 'Romance'),('10','El amante japones', 'Isabel Allende', 'La historia de amor entre la joven Alma Belasco y el jardinero japonés Ichimei conduce al lector por un recorrido a través de diversos escenarios que van desde la Polonia de la Segunda Guerra Mundial hasta el San Francisco de nuestros días «A los veintidós años, sospechando que tenían el tiempo contado, Ichimei y Alma se atragantaron de amor para consumirlo entero, pero mientras más intentaban agotarlo, más imprudente era el deseo, y quien diga que todo fuego se apaga solo tarde o temprano, se equivoca: hay pasiones que son incendios hasta que las ahoga el destino de un zarpazo y aun así quedan brasas calientes listas para arder apenas se les da oxígeno.', '22-05-2015', 'Plaza & Janés', '725', 'Español', 'Drama') ");
    db.execSQL(tabla_favoritos);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS libros");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS libros (Id text, Titulo text, Autor text, Sinopsis text, FechaDePublicacion text, Editorial text, CantidadDePaginas text, Idioma text, Categorias text)");
    db.execSQL("insert into libros values('1', 'El Resplandor', 'Stephen King', '¿Qué ha sido de Danny Torrance? Descúbrelo al final de este volumen, que incluye el inicio de Doctor Sueño, la continuación de El resplandor. REDRUM. Esa es la palabra que Danny había visto en el espejo. Y, aunque no sabía leer, entendió que era un mensaje de horror. Tenía cinco años, y a esa edad pocos niños son conscientes de que los espejos invierten las imágenes, y menos aún diferencian entre realidad y fantasía. Pero Danny tenía pruebas de que sus fantasías relacionadas con el resplandor del espejo acabarían cumpliéndose.', '28-01-1977', 'Doubleday', '447', 'Ingles', 'Terror'), ('2', 'Forbidden', 'Tabitha Suzuma', 'No podemos. Si empezamos, ¿cómo vamos a pararlo? Lochan y Maya siempre se han sentido más amigos que hermanos. Ante la incapacidad de cuidarlos de su madre alcohólica y la ausencia de un padre que los abandonó, los dos jóvenes deben hacerse cargo de sus tres hermanos menores y esconder su situación a los servicios sociales, porque ninguno de los dos es mayor de edad. La responsabilidad que comparten y las dificultades a las que se enfrentan les unen, hasta empujarlos a enamorarse. Ambos saben que su relación está mal y que no debe continuar, pero al mismo tiempo no pueden controlar sus emociones y la atracción que los domina.', '10-05-2010', 'OZ', '387', 'Español', 'Ficción'),('3', 'Cazadores de Sombras', 'Harald Zwart', 'En la ciudad de Nueva York, una adolescente aparentemente común llamada Clary Fray descubre que ella desciende de una línea de guerreros, mitad ángeles, quienes protegen a la humanidad de los demonios. Después de que su madre desaparece, Clary une fuerzas con un grupo de cazadores de sombras e ingresa al Inframundo, un sitio peligroso y alterno lleno de demonios, brujos, vampiros, hombres lobo y criaturas sobrenaturales.', '22-07-2013', 'Simon & Schuster', '948', 'Español', 'Ficción'),('4', 'Beautiful Disaster', 'Jamie McGuire', 'La chica buena Abby no bebe, no se mete en líos y trabaja muy duro. Cree que ha enterrado su oscuro pasado, pero cuando llega a la universidad, un rompecorazones conocido por sis ligues de una noche pone en peligro su sueño de una nueva vida. El chico malo Travis Maddox , sexy, musculoso y cubierto de tatuajes, es justamente el tipo de chico que le atrae a Abby, justamente lo que quiere evitar. Dedica sus noches a ganar dinero en un club de lucha itinerante y sus dias a ser el estudiante ejemplar y el seductor mas popular del campus. Toda una mezcla explosiva. Intrigado por el rechazo de Abby, Travis intenta colarse en su vida proponiendole una apuesta que trastocará sus mundos y lo cambiará todo.', '26-05-2011', 'Simon & Schuster', '567', 'Ingles', 'Romance'),('5', 'Hush Hush', 'Becca Fitzpatrick', 'Cuando Patch se convierte en su nuevo compañero de laboratorio de biología, Nora siente a la vez atracción y repulsión hacia este extraño personaje que parece tener acceso a sus pensamientos. Luego se entera de que Patch es un ángel caído que quiere convertirse en humano.', '13-10-2009', 'Ediciones B', '647', 'Ingles', 'Romance'),('6', 'Los juegos del hambre', 'Collins Suzanne', 'En lo que alguna vez fue Norteamérica, la Capital de Panem mantiene sus 12 distritos obligándolos a seleccionar a un niño y a una niña, llamados Tributos, a competir en un evento televisado nacionalmente llamados Juegos del Hambre. Cada ciudadano debe ver pelear a muerte a los jóvenes. El Trbuto del Distrito 12, Katniss Everdeen sólo confía en sus habilidades de caza y buenos instintos en una arena en donde debe sobrevivir contra la humanidad.', '14-09-2008', 'Rba-Molino', '847', 'Español', 'Fantasía'),('7', 'Misery', 'Stephen King', 'Un autor se recupera de un accidente y es cuidado por una admiradora que le insiste escribir un libro sólo para ella.', '08-06-1987', 'Viking Press', '320', 'Ingles', 'Terror'),('8', 'Oscuros', 'Kate Lauren', 'La historia de Daniel y Luce, dos almas predestinadas a encontrarse y condenadas a perderse... Helstone, Inglaterra, 1854. Es noche cerrada y dos jóvenes conversan en una remota casa de campo. Se sienten irresistiblemente atraídos el uno por el otro, pero él insiste en que no pueden estar juntos.', '08-12-2009', 'Penguin Random House', '416', 'Ingles', 'Drama'),('9', 'Eleanor & Park', 'Rowell Rainbow', 'Dos chicos de un colegio, que se conocen por una situación fortuita en el autobús escolar, haciendo que de poco a poco su amistad vaya evolucionando en algo más. Pero no todo en la vida es fácil, al final, los dos protagonistas tendrán que luchar por mantenerse juntos, he impedir que el padrastro de Eleanor los separen para siempre.', '07-10-2012', 'Aguilar', '333', 'Ingles', 'Romance'),('10','El amante japones', 'Isabel Allende', 'La historia de amor entre la joven Alma Belasco y el jardinero japonés Ichimei conduce al lector por un recorrido a través de diversos escenarios que van desde la Polonia de la Segunda Guerra Mundial hasta el San Francisco de nuestros días «A los veintidós años, sospechando que tenían el tiempo contado, Ichimei y Alma se atragantaron de amor para consumirlo entero, pero mientras más intentaban agotarlo, más imprudente era el deseo, y quien diga que todo fuego se apaga solo tarde o temprano, se equivoca: hay pasiones que son incendios hasta que las ahoga el destino de un zarpazo y aun así quedan brasas calientes listas para arder apenas se les da oxígeno.', '22-05-2015', 'Plaza & Janés', '725', 'Español', 'Drama') ");
    db.execSQL(tabla_favoritos);
}

public void insertarLibro(String titulo) {
    SQLiteDatabase bd = getWritableDatabase();
    if(bd != null){
        bd.execSQL("INSERT INTO favoritos VALUES('"+titulo+"')");
        bd.close();
    }
}
```

Mi clase completa donde elimino el elemento del ListView:

```
public class ListaFavoritos extends AppCompatActivity implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

ListView listaFavoritos;
ArrayList<String> listaInfo;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador;
ArrayList<Favoritos> listaLibros; 
BaseDeDatos conn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.favoritos);

    conn = new BaseDeDatos(this);

    listaFavoritos = findViewById(R.id.lvFavoritos);

    consultarFav();

    listaFavoritos.setLongClickable(true);
    listaFavoritos.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            SQLiteDatabase db=conn.getWritableDatabase();
            db.rawQuery("DELETE FROM favoritos", null)
                listaInfo.remove(i);
                adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }

    });

    adaptador = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listaInfo);
    listaFavoritos.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    listaFavoritos.setAdapter(adaptador);
}

private void consultarFav() {
    SQLiteDatabase db=conn.getReadableDatabase();
    Favoritos fav = null;
    listaLibros = new ArrayList<Favoritos>();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM favoritos" ,null );

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        fav = new Favoritos();
        fav.setTitulo(cursor.getString(0));
        listaLibros.add(fav);
    }
    obtenerLista();
}

private void obtenerLista() {
    listaInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0; i<listaLibros.size();i++){
        listaInfo.add(listaLibros.get(i).getTitulo()+"");
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
}
}
```

Comment: `DELETE FROM favoritos` debe llevar un `where`, `"DELETE FROM favoritos WHERE titulo ="listaLibros.get(i)` asumiendo qu quieres borrar por titulo

Comment: Hola @Rodrigo  agregué dos formas de realizar esto, una mediante el id y otra mediante el titulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas usar el id para determinar el registro a eliminar:

Debes eliminar el elemento de acuerdo a el id, de acuerdo a tu script para agregar elementos a la base de datos el primer elemento tiene id 1 por lo tanto tienes agregar +1 a la variable `position` (i).

**Un punto importante es que el método [rawQuery()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) se usa para seleccionar, para realizar modificaciones en la base de datos debes usar [execSQL()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#execSQL(java.lang.String)).**

> **[execSQL()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#execSQL(java.lang.String))** Ejecute una sola instrucción SQL que NO sea una SELECT
>   o cualquier otra instrucción SQL que devuelva datos.

Ejemplo:

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM favoritos where id="+ idElemento);
```

Revisa el cambio:

```
  listaFavoritos.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            SQLiteDatabase db=conn.getWritableDatabase();
            int idElemento = i + 1;
           // db.rawQuery("DELETE FROM favoritos where id="+ idElemento  , null);
              db.execSQL("DELETE FROM favoritos where id="+ idElemento);
                listaInfo.remove(i);
                adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }

    });
```

---

Otra forma, si desearas eliminar el elemento en base a su titulo, recuerda que debes definir la cadena del titulo entre comillas:

```
"DELETE FROM favoritos WHERE titulo ='"+listaLibros.get(i).getTitulo()+"'"
```

Revisa el cambio:

```
  listaFavoritos.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            SQLiteDatabase db=conn.getWritableDatabase();

            //db.rawQuery("DELETE FROM favoritos WHERE titulo ='"+listaLibros.get(i).getTitulo()+"'"  , null);
             db.execSQL("DELETE FROM favoritos WHERE titulo ='"+listaLibros.get(i).getTitulo()+"'");
                listaInfo.remove(i);
                adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Comment: lo hago de esta manera y no me da error, me elimina el elemento en cuestión del ListView, pero cuando salgo y vuelvo a entrar, me vuelve a aparecer

Comment: @Rodrigo de cual de las dos formas ? que muestra el LogCat?

Comment: de la segunda forma, eliminandolo por el nombre de titulo. El Logcat no me muestra nada porque la app no dá error, simplemente cuando salgo de la activity donde tengo el ListView y vuelvo a entrar, me vuelven a aparecer los elementos removidos.

Comment: también lo acabo de probar de la primer manera, eliminandolo por id, y me pasa exactamente lo mismo. No dá error, me borra el elemento de la ListView, pero cuando salgo y vuelvo a entrar a la activity con el ListView, me vuelven a aparecer.

Comment: acabo de corroborar con el SQLite Data Browser que a pesar de hacer el "DELETE FROM ...." los elementos nunca se eliminan de la Base De Datos, por algún motivo. @Jorgesys

Comment: Ya se que sucede, tratas de modificar una tabla y rawQuery() se usa para seleccionar exclusivamente, usa: db.execSQL("DELETE FROM favoritos WHERE titulo ='"+listaLibros.get(i).getTitulo()+"'"); confirmame para actualizar mi respuesta

Comment: sii! era eso! también hay que sacar el parámetro de , null luego de la query. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Excelente @Rodrigo, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tu haces es eliminar todos las filas de la base de datos

```
            db.rawQuery("DELETE FROM favoritos", null)
```

Debes añadir una clausura WHERE y luego añadir la condición que desees, en tu caso si quieres eliminar por titulo seria

```
        db.rawQuery("DELETE FROM favoritos WHERE titulo ="+listaLibros.get(i).getTitulo(), null)
```

Comment: lo hice como dices, pero me arroja el siguiente error:     Process: com.example.rodrigo.libros, PID: 11741
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "de": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM favoritos WHERE titulo = Harry Potter

Comment: prueba a meter entre comillas simples el texto

Comment: no le gusta, me da error

Comment: porque no pruebas a obtener el id del elemento que toques y lo eliminas por id?

Comment: si justo eso acabo de probar, ahora no me dá error, me elimina el elemento del ListView, pero cuando salgo y vuelvo a entrar a la activity, me vuelven a aparecer los elementos eliminados.

Comment: porque no intentas crear la lista en un recyclerView?